# What to update in git when I changed my username?

Tags: git, github, repository

I just changed my username in Github. Now I am trying to get all my local stuff working again. I already did these things but I think that I am missing something:

- changed username in Github
- changed git username in local repository
- updates remotes so that they point to the correct address

I read that I also have to update gitmodules. What does that mean / how do I do that? Also, since changing my username my blog at 'username.github.io' does not work anymore. What can I do about that?

Comment: You don't need to change your username in the local repo, that is independent. Git identifies you by your email address and that has no reason to change (did it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget to change the email address in your local repos if the one on GitHub as changed as well.

You can edit your `.gitmodules` file in order to change the url of an upstream repo for a given submodule, and then run a:

```
git submodule sync
```